# Does webapps integrates with existing VMs on Azure?

Tags: azure, web-applications, virtual-machine, integration

I have an existing linux VM on Azure that has PHP + MySql legacy system running on it

I also have a Flask Webapp running under same Azure subscription

is it possible to the Python WebApp reach the existing MySql database running on Linux VM using the existing internal network ?

AB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you want to access MySql database on the Azure VM from Azure web app hosted in azure app service. If so, it's possible to [integrate your app with an Azure Virtual Network](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet).

You could have a quick start in that document, just note that there are two forms to the VNet Integration feature:

- [Reginal VNet integration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet#regional-vnet-integration). One version enables integration with VNets in the **same region**. Currently, this feature is still in preview but is supported for Windows app production workloads and Linux Web App for development and integration testing purposes. Read more details [here](https://github.com/Azure/app-service-linux-docs/blob/master/app_service_linux_vnet_integration.md).
- [Gateway required VNet Integration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet#gateway-required-vnet-integration). The other version enables integration with VNets in **other regions or with Classic VNets**. This version requires the deployment of a Virtual Network Gateway into your VNet. It is only supported by Windows apps.

Additionally, Since VNet Integration is extended to use Azure container instance. For Linux web app, you could deploy it on Azure container instance in a VNet. See the [template](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/templates/101-aci-vnet/). This feature is currently in preview and you could know some limitations about [deploying container instances into an Azure virtual network.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-vnet)

If your web app is hosting on other Azure services like Azure VM, you could use VNet to VNet connection or VNet peering or VPN connection to enable the communication between the two different virtual networks. Read more details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-howto-vnet-vnet-resource-manager-portal).

Hope this could help you.

Comment: Thanks Nancy, so either ways it looks like works only for Windows apps then?

Comment: Currently, New Vnet integration for Linux web app is in preview for development and integration testing purposes and you also could select to deploy Linux web app on a container. Check my edit.